# rigify causing my character mesh to become smaller and out of place

Tags: armature, rigify

I'm trying to learn how to use rigify on blender and every time I generate a rig, it causes the mesh to become smaller and rotated. I applied the transformations for both the rig and mesh, but it still does it. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/zl3mXu1t90U) YT video from CGDive helps.